# Share a resource between two paths

Tags: ember.js, resources, routes

I am fairly new to JS and Ember, so please bear with me =)

In my app there are two types of users: a superuser, and program managers. The superuser makes new programs and assigns a manager to them. I then need the program managers to be able to go to a page where they can choose what program they want to work on and have things paths from there.

This is how my current NON-WORKING router.coffee file looks:

```
App.Router.map ->

@resource 'su', ->

  @resource 'programs', ->
    @route 'new'
    @route 'edit', path: ':program_id/edit'

  @resource 'pm', ->
    @resource 'programs', path: 'pm/programs', ->
      @resource 'projects', path: ':program_id/projects', ->
       @route 'new'
       @route 'edit', path: ':project_id/edit'
```

I think having programs listed as a resource twice is causing my app to get a "uncaught typeerror cannot call method "shouldSupercede" of undefined" because it works when i take out programs from pm.

I am unsure of how to add a page that lists all the programs a pm is assigned to

Comment: I'm not very familiar with coffeescript, but I created a sample app in JSBin just to see if I could get the routes to work like you have them laid out.  It seems to be working.  You can see the example [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fupacane/1/edit).

If you don't already, I would suggest installing [Ember Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector) in Chrome and taking a look at the routes that are being defined in your app.  You can load up the example [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fupacane#/su) and see how they're working in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should think of a **resource** as something that matches with a **data model**, and a route as an action that can be performed on that data model, or with it as basis. It is common error in Ember beginners to try to somehow put the model relations in the way routes are organized. The typical example of 'post' and 'comment' resources has the trap that comments belong to 1 post. And even there the resource nesting is probably unneeded, as the complexity should rely in the model relations, not in the routing.

So in general, the architecture you propose is going to scale badly. Specially if at some point you decide that e.g. 2 project managers participate in the same program. Hence, there is no need to nest routes inside the others in this case (as it occurs for example, when putting the 'pm' resource and routes inside the 'su' resource).

I would keep all entities separated at route level, and then do the work establishing the relations between the models. You can work this by hand if you like, or you could let e.g. Ember Data do that for you (first please check if it suits your needs, as it might be oversized). Your backend should know which projects/programs, a user should be able to see.

So here's my suggestion to organize routes: (I even probably do just a simple 'user' resource and let the superuser or project manager status be a property in the model, but I don't know your data models, so let's assume they have different data structure...)

```js
App.Router.map ->

  @resource 'su'

  @resource 'project_managers' path: '/project_managers' ->
    @route 'index' 
    @resource 'project_manager', path: '/:project_manager_id', ->
       @route 'show, path: '/' #at this route you could show info about the project manager, and its programs could be accessible through its model, like, e.g. model.programs.
       @route 'new', path: '/new'
       @route 'edit', path: '/edit'
       @route 'programs', path: '/programs' #or you could set a new route and a view for seeing the programs for this pm. (note *1)


  @resource 'programs', path: '/programs' ->
    @route 'index' #this route would provide a list of all programs (naturally you can decide which one are visible to the current user) 
    @resource 'program', path: '/:program_id', ->
       @route 'show, path: '/'
       @route 'new', path: '/new'
       @route 'edit', path: '/edit'

      
  @resource 'projects', path: '/projects', ->
    @route 'index'
    @resource 'project', path: '/:project_id', ->
       @route 'show, path: '/'
       @route 'new', path: '/new'
       @route 'edit', path: '/edit'
```

*1: Because even in case that from there you'd like to navigate further to the specific program, there is no gain in going to a path such as '/project_managers/35/programs/4' rather than '/programs/4'. Even if the URL for an API request could be the first one (quite probable if you operate a Rails backend).

Sorry if the answer was too long, I hope it helped you to have a clearer view! :)

Comment: Ah! And please note I did not use the 'pm' abbreviation for 'project manager'... 

It is a matter of taste, but as you mention you are starting, I would in general not recommend you to save some characters that can eventually provide more readability to the code. Not to mention that in big applications you might find the point where some abbreviations are the same (collisions... BOOM!!)